# How display timer in JLabel

Tags: java, swing

I want to display a timer in my JLabel. So I have build this code, it works, but I don't know if this code is correct.

```
public void cswing(){
   labelTempoGara = new TimeRefreshRace();
   labelTempoGara.start();
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TimeRefreshRace extends JLabel implements Runnable {

    private boolean isAlive = false;

    public void start() {
        threadTempoCorsa = new Thread(this);
        isAlive = true;
        threadTempoCorsa.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        int tempoInSecondi = programma.getTempoGara() % 60;
        int minuti = programma.getTempoGara() / 60;
        while (isAlive) {
            try {
                if (minuti <= 0 && tempoInSecondi<=1) {
                    isRun=false;
                    this.setText("00:00");
                    isAlive = false;
                    salvaDatiCorsa();
                    break;
                }
                if(tempoInSecondi<=1){
                    minuti--;
                    tempoInSecondi=60;
                }
                --tempoInSecondi;
                this.setText(minuti+":"+ tempoInSecondi);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.logStackTrace(e);
            }
        }

    }

    public void kill() {
        isAlive = false;
        isRun=false;
    }

}//fine autoclass
```

I repeat, this code works, but I don't know if is correct use JLabel with Runnable thread or not

Comment: Use javax.swingTimer Luke. Modifing of swing component outside of Swing thread (Event Dispatcher Thread) can produce unexplainable problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example reworked with `javax.swing.Timer`
Because you haven't provied a runnable example I cannot test whether it works, but I hope you can fix problems, if they exists.

**Attention** Don't import `java.util.Timer` it's another class which also need synchronization with Swing thread (like thread in your example).

```
class TimeRefreshRace extends JLabel implements ActionListener {

    private Timer timer;

    public void start() {
        timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        int tempoInSecondi = programma.getTempoGara() % 60;
        int minuti = programma.getTempoGara() / 60;
        if (minuti <= 0 && tempoInSecondi<=1) {
            this.setText("00:00");
            salvaDatiCorsa();
            break;
        }
        if(tempoInSecondi<=1){
            minuti--;
            tempoInSecondi=60;
        }
        --tempoInSecondi;
        this.setText(minuti+":"+ tempoInSecondi);

    }

    public void kill() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.stop()
        }
    }

}//fine autoclass
```